# Is this a correct implementation of the Decorator pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

### Main.java

```
package com.example.decorator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response response = new Response();
        View head = new View("<title>Hello, world!</title>");
        View body = new View("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
        response.setContent(new HtmlLayout(head, body));
        response.render();
    }
}
```

### Response.java

```
package com.example.decorator;

public class Response {
    private Response content;
    public Response () {}
    public <T extends Response> void setContent(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public void render() {
        this.content.render();
    };
}
```

### View.java

```
package com.example.decorator;

public class View extends Response {
    private String content;
    public View(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
    public void render() {
        System.out.println(this.content);
    }
}
```

### Layout.java

```
package com.example.decorator;

public class Layout extends Response {
    private Response view;
    public <T extends Response> Layout(T view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    public void render() {
        this.view.render();
    }
}
```

### HtmlLayout.java

```
package com.example.decorator;

public class HtmlLayout extends Response {
    private Response head;
    private Response body;
    public <T extends Response> HtmlLayout(T head, T body) {
        this.head = head;
        this.body = body;
    }
    public void render() {
        System.out.println("<!doctype html>");
        System.out.println("<html>");
        System.out.println("<head>");
        this.head.render();
        System.out.println("</head>");
        System.out.println("<body>");
        this.body.render();
        System.out.println("</body>");
        System.out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Decorator pattern is used when you want an object of type(interface) A to do more than it does currently. An example would be: Web page(logical screen) that does fit your physical screen does not need scroll bar. however, if the page(logical screen)  does not fit the physical screen, you have to decorate it with scroll bar.
In GOF words: The intent of Decorator is to attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically.

In code that would look like:

```
interface LogicalScreen {
  void render(String physical );
}
```

An implementation:

```
class SimpleScreen implements LogicalScreen {
  public void render(String physical) {
    // render itself
  }
}
```

Implementation of decorator:

```
class ScreenWithScrollbar implements LogicalScreen {
  private final LogicalScreen decoratd;

  public ScreenWithScrollbar(LogicalScreen decorated) {
    this.decoratd = decorated;
  }

  public void render(String physical) {
    // render scroll bar
    // ...
    // render the decorated
    decoratd.render(physical);
    // eventually do some more stuff
  }

  public doScroll() {}
}
```

How is wired:

```
public class WhatIsDecorator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LogicalScreen l1 = new SimpleScreen();
    LogicalScreen ds = new ScreenWithScrollbar(l1);

    ds.render("MyMonitor");
  }
}
```

You can chain like this as many as you need. Decorator2(Decorator1(Simple)) ...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I've looked over for short:

- Change your Response to an interface
- Your View.java does not match a decorator pattern really, so remove the extends of Response e.g.

Best regards